# Git interactive rebase without opening the editor

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Git allows certain commands to create or modify commits without opening the editor first, for example:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git commit --fixup=HEAD^
```

I have set `rebase.autosquash` to `true`, so that the todo list for an interactive rebase is automatically reordered. Is there a way to immediately perform the rebase, without opening the editor first, something like:

```
git rebase -i --no-edit HEAD~3
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would you not want the editor?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Maybe for batch operations on the server side. The question is, why does `--autosquash` require `--interactive`...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### TL;DR answer: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase -i HEAD~3`

You can't stop `git rebase --interactive` from running the "sequence editor" (that's the edit command on the "sequence file" containing the various pick, etc., commands).  However, if you examine the interactive rebase script:

```
$ vim $(git --exec-path)/git-rebase--interactive
```

you'll find code like this near line 230 or so:

```
git_sequence_editor () {
    if test -z "$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR"
    then
        GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="$(git config sequence.editor)"
        if [ -z "$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR" ]
        then
            GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="$(git var GIT_EDITOR)" || return $?
        fi
    fi

    eval "$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR" '"$@"'
}
```

Thus, you simply need to set the sequence editor to an "edit" command that does nothing and then succeeds, such as the shell's built-in `:` command, or the `true` command.

(Any of `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, the configured `sequence.editor`, or `$GIT_EDITOR` will suffice for this, though the obvious best one to use is the first.)

Comment: This stops it from running, but it was not equivalent to running the editor and typing `:wq` -- that is, the editor didn't run, but the rebase didn't complete.  I ran it within a git alias to a shell function, if that matters: `cadd =  "!f() {  git commit --fixup=$1; GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase -i --autosquash $1^; }; f"`

Comment: @Jonah: Odd ... do you have an example with details?

Answer (score 19):

Instead of using the `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable, you can use `-c` to pass configuration to git:

```
git -c sequence.editor=: rebase --autosquash --interactive origin/master
```

Works well for triggering editor-free rebases from within your editor (i.e., using fugitive's `:Git` command in vim).

Answer (score 9):

As an illustration of [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094904/6309) (`GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=:`) see Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019):

When `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` is set, the command was incorrectly started when modes of "git rebase" that implicitly uses the machinery for the interactive rebase are run, which has been corrected.

See [commit 891d4a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/891d4a0313edc03f7e2ecb96edec5d30dc182294) (28 Jan 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 69dd6e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69dd6e57374f4aa5dcda0736529be47b16a08afe), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### implicit interactive rebase: don't run sequence editor

> If `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` is set then rebase runs it when executing
> implicit interactive rebases which are supposed to appear
> non-interactive to the user.
> Fix this by setting `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=:` rather than `GIT_EDITOR=:.`

---

Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) documents that environment variable.

See [commit 902a126](https://github.com/git/git/commit/902a126eca2d46b34dab822f1a1861bc2ce3cf48) (31 Aug 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed9d833](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed9d8331d25eae29aa24a2859bde6450aebe0bc3), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/902a126eca2d46b34dab822f1a1861bc2ce3cf48): mention `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` and '`sequence.editor`' more
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> The environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, and the configuration variable '`sequence.editor`', which were added in [821881d88d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/821881d88d3012a64a52ece9a8c2571ca00c35cd) ("`rebase -i`": support special-purpose editor to edit insn sheet, 2011-10-17), are mentioned in the `[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/902a126eca2d46b34dab822f1a1861bc2ce3cf48/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup>`  man page but not anywhere else.
>
> Add `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to the list of environment variables in `git`.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/902a126eca2d46b34dab822f1a1861bc2ce3cf48/Documentation/git.txt#L608-L613):

> ### `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`:
>
> This environment variable overrides the configured Git editor
> when editing the todo list of an interactive rebase.
> See also `git rebase` and the `sequence.editor` option in `git config`.