# Git: `rebase -i` doesn't work (it doesn't open `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo`)

Tags: git, git-rebase

In normal process of `git rebase -i` would be look like this (`=>` means terminal command prompt):

```
=> git logg
* 7bec976 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Update JANDI task: add Bitcoin topic
* e03aecc Update production.txt:remove pandas and set celery-beat version
* baaaf4b Update JANDI task: Fix link bug
* bb422af Update Procfile: on flower
* 733ca41 Implement JANDI task
```

And `rebase -i`:

```
=> git rebase -i 733ca41
```

It would open `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` via editor:

```
1 pick bb422af Update Procfile: on flower
2 pick baaaf4b Update JANDI task: Fix link bug
3 pick e03aecc Update production.txt:remove pandas and set celery-beat version
4 pick 7bec976 Update JANDI task: add Bitcoin topic
5
6 # Rebase 733ca41..7bec976 onto 733ca41 (4 commands)
7 #
8 # Commands:
9 # p, pick = use commit
10 # r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
11 # e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
12 # s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
13 # f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
14 # x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
15 # d, drop = remove commit
16 #
17 # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
18 #
19 # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
20 #
21 # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
22 #
23 # Note that empty commits are commented out
```

HOWEVER, on my `Linux 16.04 LTS`, it behaves like this:

```
=> git rebase -i 733ca41
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/develop.
=>
```

Nothing opened, nothing happened...

I have no idea what's wrong with this command. Any other git commands work perfectly except `rebase -i`

Need your helps. Thanks

Comment: Check whether your Git editor settings are correct (e.g., try running `git config --edit`). That's one shot-in-the-dark, as it is not at all clear what is happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the issue persists with the latest 2.16.x version of Git.

But first, as [seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094904/6309), check the value of the environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`.
If set to '`:`', that would make the editor step invisible.

Note: setting the [`sequence.editor` configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-sequenceeditor) should not have been necessary:

> When not configured the default commit message editor is used instead.

So make sure instead that [`core.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreeditor) is set properly, as illustrated in "[Associating text editors with Git](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/)".

Comment: Is your method different with setting `sequence.editor`?

Comment: @user3595632 it is more general and will work for all instances where an editor is needed. Again, in your case, "**when [sequence.editor] is not configured, the default commit message editor is used instead**".

Comment: Ok, I will select yours as an solution. Thanks : )

Answer (score 2):

`git config --global sequence.editor vim` would work :)