# change git history (commit date) of *n* commits with shell script

Tags: git, shell, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

The big picture of my problem:

**I want to write a script to [change the history](https://codewithhugo.com/change-the-date-of-a-git-commit/) of the last n commits to *today***, for example: `./myscript.sh 5` will change the *commit dates* of the last 5 commits to *today*.

From [this link](https://codewithhugo.com/change-the-date-of-a-git-commit/), I can either:

1. Set the date of the *last commit* to the *current date*
2. Set the date of the *last commit* to an *arbitrary date*
3. Set the date of an *arbitrary commit* to an *arbitrary or current date*

Because what I want is to change the history of the last **n commits**, not only 1, so I have to go with the 3rd technique, which need to invoke `git rebase -i` and an editor open. I want to write a script to automate this task.

---

Here's how the task is done manually *(change the commit dates of last 5 commits to today)*:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

then it opens the editor

```
pick 81888d1 committed 9 months ago
pick 7363124 committed a month ago
pick eea43f7 committed yesterday
pick 48c3e85 committed yesterday
pick a62cbec commit recently
# change all the `pick` to `edit`
```

close the editor, repeat the following for 5 times

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
git rebase --continue
```

Done.

---

Constraints: Because I know ahead of time that the part I do in editor is to replace all `pick` keywords with `edit`, so I want it to be done silently. Just type `./myscript.sh 5` and the job done, no editors opened. How can I do this *(in script)*?

---

With the help of the answers, here's my final script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# wish design:
#./myscript.sh [number of days]
#./myscript.sh 5 # make the last 5 commits's commit dates to today

declare -r integer_pattern="^[0-9]+$"

if [[ $1 =~ $integer_pattern ]]; then
  count=$1

  GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick /e /'" git rebase -i "HEAD~$count"

  for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do
    GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
    git rebase --continue
  done

else
  echo "invalid argument [number of days] $1"

fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git interactive rebase without opening the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094595/git-interactive-rebase-without-opening-the-editor)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+interactive+automatic

Comment: It looks like someone's asked a related question, but I don't understand what they've talked about. Can someone explain it in a more beginner-friendly manner? Like in my case what I should do? What should I type on the terminal? What should I write on my script to get the job done?

Comment: Is there a _specific_ need to use **interactive** rebase? I mean... if you want your script to do stuff without user intervention, why do you want to run rebase **interactively** in the first place? I guess you could have fun with either rebase _without -i_ or with cherry-picks, and then there's no need to care about the interactive rebase control-by-the-editor part.

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm mostly a beginner trying to playing around with the limited knowledge I've already known. Honestly all I knew about `rebase` is `rebase -i` to *combine* multiple commits into one. What I'm doing is writing a script to combine `n` last commits into one and `edit/e` when `rebase -i` to [change the *date commit* to *today*](https://codewithhugo.com/change-the-date-of-a-git-commit/). Like `./myscript.sh 5` will combine last 5 commits into one and change the date commit of that combined commit to *today*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner).

Interactive rebase opens the default `$EDITOR` on the commit list. It can be also overriden by env variable called `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, so you need to intercept the call and use this variable with some script

Run: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<script> git rebase -i <params>`. Your `<script>` should accept a single argument: the path to the file containing the standard rebase commit list. It should rewrite it in-place and exit. Usual rebase processing happens after that.

Example:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick /e /'" git rebase -i
```

But you can use also some bash/python/whatever script instead.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you're delivering what I want but I don't understand all yet, I'll mark accepted answer when I totally solved my problem. Sorry because I'm still a beginner, there're terms I don't know like *`$EDITOR` on the commit list*,  *env variable called `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`*,  ... But I think I'll figure them out soon.

Answer (score 2):

Squashing n commits into one can be done without rebase interactive.... or even rebase at all. To squash the last 5 commits you can do this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
git commit -m "some comment"
```

And you are done

Comment: Really sorry, I described my problem incorrectly, I don't need to combine those commits into one, just to change their commit dates, as I edit my question accordingly. Anyway this answer really helped me learn a new thing, if someday I need to combine last 5 commits and change its commit date (as I misdescribed), this'll be obviously the answer that'd save my day.