# Is there a way to have a commit per day and per file automatically in git?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit, git-rewrite-history

I use `git-auto-commit-mode` (https://github.com/ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode) in Emacs to preserve my files automatically sync with my repo.

However, I got a massive list of commits per day (the package makes a commit in every save). At the end of the day I finish with something like this

```
Sat Feb 4 12:57:14 2023 fileA.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:56:52 2023 fileA.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:55:57 2023 fileA.txt
--------- Different file --------
Sat Feb 4 12:54:47 2023 fileB.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:45:04 2023 fileB.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:45:04 2023 fileB.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:44:51 2023 fileB.txt
--------- Different day ---------
Fri Feb 3 14:44:27 2023 fileA.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:44:05 2023 fileA.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:41:35 2023 fileA.txt
--------- Different file --------
Fri Feb 3 14:40:54 2023 fileB.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:40:17 2023 fileB.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:39:14 2023 fileB.txt
```

I would like to have a cleaner history like this

```
Sat Feb 4 12:57:14 2023 fileA.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:54:47 2023 fileB.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:44:27 2023 fileA.txt
Fri Feb 3 14:40:54 2023 fileB.txt
```

Where I preserve the last commit day per day and per file.

I can do this using `git rebase` manually, but I couldn't figure it out how to do it automatically for the whole history, taking account deletions and renames.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Automating this might be slightly harder if it's possible for multiple files to be edited in a single commit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to VonC (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75349092/7529776)  I have a partial solution to the problem

After loading `git-auto-commit-mode` you can do this

```
(defun my-commit-message (file)
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-day (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))
        (previous-day (file-name-nondirectory (shell-command-to-string "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%as' HEAD")))
        (current-file (file-name-nondirectory file))
        (previous-file (file-name-nondirectory (shell-command-to-string "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%s' HEAD"))))
    (if (and (string= current-file previous-file)
             (string= current-day previous-day))
        (concat "squash! "  (gac-relative-file-name file))
      (gac-relative-file-name file))))

(setq gac-default-message #'my-commit-message)
```

and then you can run

```
git -c sequence.editor=: rebase --autosquash --interactive origin/main
```

Or use magit's rebase with the autosquash flag.

The problem remaining is this method only modifies the history from the present, but not in the past.

**Edit: I added a new version of `my-commit-message` where it checks if the day also has changed.**

Comment: Great, well done! Adding `squash!` should help indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a [prefix to the commit messages of git-auto-commit-mode](https://github.com/ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode/issues/43#issuecomment-1341107298), then you can get:

```
squash!Sat Feb 4 12:57:14 2023 fileA.txt
squash!Sat Feb 4 12:56:52 2023 fileA.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:55:57 2023 fileA.txt
--------- Different file --------
squash!Sat Feb 4 12:54:47 2023 fileB.txt
squash!Sat Feb 4 12:45:04 2023 fileB.txt
squash!Sat Feb 4 12:45:04 2023 fileB.txt
Sat Feb 4 12:44:51 2023 fileB.txt
```

That means your `defun my-commit-message` must check if the commit right before the new one is:

- for the same file (add a `squash!` prefix) or
- for a different file (don't add the prefix)

Then a [`git -c sequence.editor=: rebase --autosquash --interactive origin/main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048841/6309) would be enough to automatically squash your history as you want it.

Comment: Thanks. I could craft a partial solution to the problem. I'll write it as a possible answer.