# git, squash multiple commits, one by one

Tags: git

I have a set of commits, in reverse `git log` order, in the same flat branch:

```
2018-01-01 AAAA1 "Some work 1"  # Changes on directory
2018-06-01 SOME_OTHER_COMMIT "Unrelated commit in order"
2019-01-02 BBBB1 "Some work 2"  # Changes on directory
.....
2018-01-01 AAAA2 "Some work 1"  # Changes on file
2019-01-02 BBBB2 "Some work 2"  # Changes on file
```

This is the result of moving some code with history from another repo. Directory moved out with `git subtree split` while single file via `git -am`, patch. Though it is unrelated to the original question while explaining the repository state

Now, I scripted the iteration of related commits. Grouping them by commit time.

E.g.,

```
for_each matching_commit_hash_pair
    Rebase and squash "2018-01-01 AAAA1" + "2018-01-01 AAAA2" => "2018-01-01 AAAA-some-other-hash"
```

The question is, how this final non-interactive rebase (if rebase it is) would look like?

`git rebase --onto AAAA1 ... just_single_AAAA2 commit <same_common_message>`

Which is literally, moving sole AAAA2 commit to the past, right after AAAA1, keeping everything else the same

```
AAAA1
AAAA2
SOME_OTHER_COMMIT
BBBB1
BBBB2
```

With a final squash:

```
AAAA_SQUASHED
SOME_OTHER_COMMIT
BBBB_SQUASHED
```

While I didn't check the final squash of sequential-to-be commits, I'd expect it to be easy, same one-liner maybe

Comment: Can you not simply use `git rebase -i`, bring the commits in the right order and change `pick` to `squash` or `fixup`?

Comment: Not sure how can I embed it into the iteration script

Though the structure is flat number of these commits-to-join is huge. So, it is a big loop of commit hash pairs. And any interactive rebase is not an option. Where the commit message is clear and no commit conflicts hence objects have originally been together

Comment: And if you use `git cherry-pick`? (pseudocode: `foreach hash in commits-in-right-order: git cherry-pick hash`)

Comment: And ... delete picked commit by hash right after the cherry-pick injection? If I understood it right, it should work

Comment: You can pass a custom todo-editor to `git rebase -i`. It does not have to be a "real" editor, it could also be a script.

Comment: Why doesn’t git-rebase(1) have a `--batch` option that makes the non-interactive “interactive” mode more apparent? Wondering out loud.

Comment: Related question here: [Is there a way to split a commit into fixups for the different commits it affects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75389020/184546)

Comment: If you're willing to rerun "Now, I scripted the iteration of related commits. Grouping them by commit time." you could change the second commit message to be: "fixup! <message of matching commit>". Once you have all of those fixup commits done you can simply do `git rebase <parent-of-oldest-commit-to-be-rewritten> --autosquash -i` (Then save and exit. If you want to avoid the prompt, see the linked related question for an example.)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving issues another way around, splitting folder and file together to another repository. Duplicated commits squash are not needed this way

There are a bunch of questions and answers on how to do it, but neither is to fix my issue directly.

So, I am splitting `dir1/dir2` and `dir3/another-file.ext` with history. <=== this part is not included into SO answers

Here is my final snippet:

```bash
src_repo="source-repo-path" &&\
dst_repo="new-repo-path" &&\
branch="split-repo" &&\
cd "${src_repo}" &&\
git branch "${branch}" && git checkout "${branch}" &&\
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- dir1/dir2 dir3/another-file.ext' --prune-empty -- --all &&\
mkdir --parents "${dst_repo}" && cd "${dst_repo}" &&\
git clone --single-branch --branch "${branch}" "${src_repo}" . &&\
git remote rm origin
```

Source repository cleanup with files removed, filtered branch removal and pushing new repository are not included in the snippet