# git interactive rebase: reword without confirming each commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

I want to reword multiple (a lot) of commits in a git repository.

When I execute the following command:

```bash
git rebase --interactive HEAD~200
```

I get the following 'ui' in vim:

```
  1 pick 0c511d9 foo
  2 pick da36f6f bar
  3 ...
```

I might edit the vim buffer to look like this:

```
  1 reword 0c511d9 foo_changed
  2 reword da36f6f bar_changed_too
  3 ...
```

Now, when I confirm using `:wq`, git will pull up each individual commit in a new vim buffer.
Worse than that, it will not even remember the modifications I did to the messages
but show only the original messages.

---

Is there a way to just reword in the initial vim buffer the way I did, without having to reconfirm everything again?

I'm was hoping for some magical flag like `git rebase -i --inline-no-confirm`.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094595/git-interactive-rebase-without-opening-the-editor), but that's not quite what I want, because I still need the editor initially.

Comment: Not following.... when you specify `reword` you are asking git to open an editor so you are able to edit the content of the commit manually... that's why you see the original message **for every commit**.

Comment: @eftshift0: I just want git to use 'foo_changed' as the new commit message, without asking further questions, if that makes sense.

Comment: .... but you mean you only need to adjust **a single commit** (say, adjust the message of `HEAD~200`) and not the others?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `git` _only_ cares about the first two words - the command and the hash. It shows the message because that helps the human understand what's going on, but I think any changes to it are ignored.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm aware that that is the default behavior. That's why I'm asking if there is a flag to change that.

Comment: Oh... wait.... you _think_ that the reword will take what you wrote after the commit id as the new commit message? Oh, well... if that is the case, that's not correct.

Comment: @eftshift0: No, if you look at the question again, you will see that I changed the message for bar aswell, and (implied) for the other 198 commits after that.

Comment: Guys, I understand how git works. I'm asking if there is a config flag, custom user script, or anything like that to make rewording a large number of commits at once more convenient. That's all.

Comment: Ok.... that is not how `rebase -i` works.... but I have an idea... let me provide it as an answer.

Comment: I think at that point you'd have to go to a `filter-` tool - e.g. see "the nuclear option" in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: The key to understanding why git _can't_ just take the new commit message from the todo list is that *commit messages aren't limited to a single line*. The first line is just treated as the "summary" or "title" of the commit, with any amount of text after it. Here's a nice illustration: https://commit.style/

Comment: @IMSoP: sure, but many commit messages in practive *are* a single line. So I was hoping for some built-in convenience. I guess I'll have to write a custom script then. But I really can't imagine something like this not already existing.

Comment: @ChrisB I'd argue they _should_ have more than one line, but that's into opinions on what a "good" message is. So, I guess someone could implement an equivalent of `git commit -m` *inside* the todo list - i.e. rather than changing the meaning of `reword` in a dangerous way, add an action like `reword -m` which overwrote the message with what you wrote on the line. I guess it's just not something people need often enough to have bothered implementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the following convenience script which does what I described:

I called this `git-batch-reword.sh`.
While it worked great for me, it's obviously a bit dangerous,
so make sure to have a backup before blindly using this.

This currently drops everything after the first line of **all**
shown commit messages because of the `head -n 1` in the filter. If anybody knows a nice trick to work around that, please leave a comment.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [[ "$1" =~ ^--?h ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <git-ref>"
    exit 1
fi

commit_ref="$1"

buffer=`mktemp`

git log --format="%H %s" "$commit_ref"..HEAD > "$buffer"

sed -i "s/^/keep /" "$buffer"

vim "$buffer"
result="$?"

if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then 
    rm "$buffer"
    exit "$result"
fi

filter_cmd='(sed -n "s/^\\(reword\\|r\\)\\s\\+$GIT_COMMIT\\s\\+\\(.*\\)/\\2/p" "'$buffer'"; cat) | head -n 1'

FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "$filter_cmd" HEAD

rm "$buffer"
```

Comment: To get closer to what you first thought of start a vim server,  then make `vim --remote-wait` your editor. Your edit

Comment: @jthill: Sorry, I don't quite understand. What problem do you see with the current approach that using a vim server would solve?

Comment: No problem, just that hand-editing can be more convenient sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have like a bunch of commits you would like to adjust in a single shot without going into each one of them, you could pull it off by writing a script that would be used in `GIT_EDITOR`. Mark the commits you want to edit as `reword`. Your script will be called with the path to a file that has the comment of the *current* commit being edited, right?

Well... create a file with the commit id and a single line with the commit comment you want for it:

```
0c511d9 foo_changed
da36f6f bar_changed_too
```

Then, every time your script gets called, you could know which commit is being worked on at the moment by using `git rev-parse --short REBASE_HEAD`... then you can read from the file I said before what should be written as the comment for that commit.... then you can replace the content of the file that you got as the argument to your script with that content....... so, the script could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMENT_FILE=$1

commit_id=$( git rev-parse --short REBASE_HEAD ) # check first that this is correct, that you get the commit ID that is being reworded and not another commit

comment=$( grep $commit_id file-with-new-comments | sed 's/$commit_d //' )
echo $comment > $1
```

That is a *rough* concept.... there might be details to take care of but it should work. The biggest question is if `git rev-parse --short REBASE_HEAD` gives you the commit being reworded.